# Linking Opencv libraries in C

Tags: c, opencv, makefile

I've been attempting to write test a simple program using the opencv library. I have the following test code I found on a tutorial. I am running OSX 10.9.2 and managed (I think) to successfully install opencv on my computer using homebrew. My problem is that I cannot get this code to compile because my make file throws errors anytime I try to compile. I believe the issue is that I have not properly linked the libraries, and no amount of googling seems to have helped me solve my problem.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// This is a simple, introductory OpenCV program. The program reads an
// image from a file, inverts it, and displays the result. 
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "Conumdrum.jpeg", 0 ); //change the name (image.jpg)   according to your Image filename.
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
    return 0;
}
```

I found a sample makefile online that I've attempted to modify but to no avail, here is my makefile below:

```
# define the C compiler to use
CC = gcc

# define any compile-time flags
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
#
INCLUDES = -I/Users/MY_NAME/Projects/Tank\ Game/Webcam_Tests/Webcam_Test_v1/include

# define library paths in addition to /usr/lib
#   if I wanted to include libraries not in /usr/lib I'd specify
#   their path using -Lpath, something like:
LFLAGS = -L/Users/MY_NAME/Projects/Tank\ Game/Webcam_Tests/Webcam_Test_v1/lib

# define any libraries to link into executable:
#   if I want to link in libraries (libx.so or libx.a) I use the -llibname 
#   option, something like (this will link in libmylib.so and libm.so:
LIBS = -l libopencv_core.dylib  -lm

# define the C source files
SRCS = Webcam_Test_v1.c

# define the C object files 
#
# This uses Suffix Replacement within a macro:
#   $(name:string1=string2)
#         For each word in 'name' replace 'string1' with 'string2'
# Below we are replacing the suffix .c of all words in the macro SRCS
# with the .o suffix
#
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# define the executable file 
MAIN = mycc

#
# The following part of the makefile is generic; it can be used to 
# build any executable just by changing the definitions above and by
# deleting dependencies appended to the file from 'make depend'
#

.PHONY: depend clean

all:    $(MAIN)
    @echo  Simple compiler named mycc has been compiled

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# this is a suffix replacement rule for building .o's from .c's
# it uses automatic variables $<: the name of the prerequisite of
# the rule(a .c file) and $@: the name of the target of the rule (a .o file) 
# (see the gnu make manual section about automatic variables)
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```

Terminal gives me the following output when I try to compile:

```
gcc -Wall -g -I/Users/MY_NAME/Projects/Tank\ Game/Webcam_Tests/Webcam_Test_v1/include -c Webcam_Test_v1.c  -o Webcam_Test_v1.o
gcc -Wall -g -I/Users/MY_NAME/Projects/Tank\ Game/Webcam_Tests/Webcam_Test_v1/include -o mycc Webcam_Test_v1.o -L/Users/MY_NAME/Projects/Tank\ Game/Webcam_Tests/Webcam_Test_v1/lib -l libopencv_core.dylib  -lm
ld: library not found for -llibopencv_core.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mycc] Error
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I've been beating my head against a wall for a couple of days now trying to solve this issue. It should also be noted that I am a novice, especially when it comes to makefiles. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linker option is wrong. Try with `-lopencv_core` instead of `-l libopencv_core.dylib`.
For example, if you want to link a library which filename is `libfoo.dylib`, the right linker option is `-lfoo`.
And you will need to add `-lopencv_highgui` too.

Comment: This syntax works now so the compiler doesn't error out due to the same issue, but now I get a bunch of errors relating to "undefined symbols for my architecture". It seems as if it's acting like opencv isn't installed, but I checked that it is. Here is what I get: <code>Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvDestroyWindow", referenced from:
      _main in Webcam_Test_v1.o</code> followed by a bunch of similar errors for similar libraries, then <code>ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)</code>

Comment: Maybe these links [here](http://www.ask-coder.com/241443/opencv-c-error-in-xcode) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811378/unable-to-compile-opencv-project-with-xcode-4) will help you.